# How do I remove this round button/image/cursor?

Tags: css, html

While using Google simulator and android phone this image is not visible but when I test on iPhone then I'm getting this issue. I'm not able to figure out from it is coming. How do I remove this?

[image]

Answer (score 0):

This is just the preview cursor on google iphone simulator, if you check it on a real iphone you won't see it, so there is no solution, and no need to remove it :)

Comment: The screenshot is from real iPhone only. Infact on google iphone simulator I'm not getting this issue but on real phone it is.